# Help proving inequality $\alpha^\alpha\left(1 - \alpha \right)^{1-\alpha} \geq \beta^\alpha \left(1 - \beta\right)^{1-\alpha}$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

So I got a request from a friend to try and solve this, but I've stuck.

$$\alpha^\alpha\left(1 - \alpha \right)^{1-\alpha} \geq \beta^\alpha \left(1 - \beta\right)^{1-\alpha}$$

for $\alpha, \beta \in (0,1)$.

I have reached here:

$$\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^\alpha\geq\left(\frac{1-\beta}{1-\alpha}\right)^{1-\alpha}$$

but maybe I have to use a theorem or an already proven inequality that I can't seem to come up to. I thought trying first $0\lt\alpha\lt\beta\lt1$ and then $0\lt\beta\lt\alpha\lt1$ but can't find my way through.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x^\alpha(1-x)^{1-\alpha}$ defined for $x\in(0,1)$

Comment: Thank you for your comment @saulspatz. I've tried to give an explanation of the steps that I've taken to solve this, but the truth is that I hadn't done much to start with. Anyway, I hope someone helps me to solve this and it isn't voted down.

Comment: Look at my last comment.  That should tell you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your hint saulspatz, I will check it out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that:
$$\alpha\ln\alpha+(1-\alpha)\ln(1-\alpha)\geq\alpha\ln\beta+(1-\alpha)\ln(1-\beta).$$
Consider $f(\beta)=\alpha\ln\beta+(1-\alpha)\ln(1-\beta).$

Thus, $$f'(\beta)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\frac{1-a}{1-\beta}=\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta(1-\beta)},$$
which gives $\beta_{\max}=a$ and since $$f(\alpha)=\alpha\ln\alpha+(1-\alpha)\ln(1-\alpha),$$ we are done!